# Evitar borrado en cascada JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tengo la siguiente clase:

```
/** 
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
*
* @author Daniel
*/
@Entity
public class Usuario implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    private String username;
    @Lob
    private byte[] fotoperfil;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Nivel nivel;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private final List<Usuario> amigos=new ArrayList();
    @ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private final List<Via> viasRealizadas=new ArrayList();
    @ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private final List<PeticionAmistad> peticionesAmistad=new ArrayList();

}
```

Si elimino un Usuario quiero evitar que se eliminen en cascada los datos de las relaciones. Por ejemplo, si elimino un usuario, quiero evitar que se borren los usuarios incluídos en la lista amigos.

¿Cómo se puede conseguir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes cambiar el valor de `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` de esta forma:

```
@ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
```

Dentro de las llaves "{}" puedes colocar uno a uno los tipos de `cascade` que necesites en la relación.

Las posibilidades son: **PERSIST, MERGE, REMOVE, REFRESH, DETACH**. El `PERSIST` es para crear (INSERT INTO), el `MERGE` es para modificar (UPDATE) y el `REMOVE` es para eliminar (DELETE).

El `REFRESH` es para actualizar el estado de la entidad, con los valores que hay en la base de datos.

El último tipo `DETACH` yo nunca lo he utilizado.

Comment: Es correcto lo que dices, y de hecho, no se borra la entidad, pero el problema persiste.

La tabla intermedia que guarda la relación (usuario-usuario) tampoco se elimina, y esa sí que me interesa eliminarla.

Comment: Entonces a esa le agregas el REMOVE: `{CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE}`

Comment: Sería igual que incluir el cascade = CascadeType.ALL entonces, no?

Comment: Pero lo pondrías solo en la relación USUARIO-USUARIO, las demás quedarían sin el `REMOVE`